# Solve for $x$ the equation $1/x+\log x =a$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis

I just don't know how to find $x$. 
Solve:
$$\frac{1}{x} + \log(x) = a$$

Comment: Only integer solutions are a=1 and x=1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$
$\def\W{\operatorname{W}}\def\Wp{\operatorname{W_{0}}}\def\Wm{\operatorname{W_{-1}}}$

\begin{align} 
\tfrac1x+\ln(x)&=a
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
\ln(\exp(\tfrac1x))+\ln(x)&=a
,\\
\ln(x\exp(\tfrac1x))=a
,\\
x\exp(\tfrac1x)&=\exp(a)
,\\
\frac 1{x\exp(\tfrac1x)}&=\frac 1{\exp(a)}
\quad (x\ne 0)
,\\
\tfrac1x\,\exp(-\tfrac1x)&=\exp(-a)
,\\
-\tfrac1x\exp(-\tfrac1x)&=-\exp(-a)
,\\
\W(-\tfrac1x\,\exp(-\tfrac1x))&=\W(-\exp(-a))
,\\
-\tfrac1x&=\W(-\exp(-a))
,\\
x&=-\frac 1{\W(-\exp(-a))}
,
\end{align}

where $\W$ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Analysis of the argument of $\W(-\exp(-a))$
shows that 
\eqref{1} has
the two real solutions

\begin{align} 
x_0&=-\frac 1{\Wp(-\exp(-a))}
,\\
x_{-1}&=-\frac 1{\Wm(-\exp(-a))}
\end{align}

for all real $a>1$,

one real solution for $a=1$
\begin{align} 
x_0&=
x_{-1}=1
,
\end{align}

and that there are no real solutions for $a<1$.

$\endgroup$

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{x}+\log x
$$
defined over $(0,\infty)$. You have
$$
\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=\infty=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)
$$
so the function has an absolute minimum. Since
$$
f'(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1-x}{x^2}
$$
the minimum is at $x=1$. Conclude that the equation $f(x)=a$ has

- no solutions for ...
- one solution for ...
- two solutions for ...

Comment: When you computed your first limit, f(x) is clearly discontinuous at 0, and it has two different limits as it approaches 0 from the left and right respectively.

Comment: @Extended The function is *not* defined for $x<0$. If you prefer to use $x\to0^+$, you're welcome, but it's not necessary, as the limit is computed over the domain of $f$.

Comment: You're right since the two-sided limit does not exist.